# Apcupsd questions

Tags: ups

I have a UPS and thought this might be of benefit.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-centos-rhel-install-apcups/

Linux: Configure and Control APC SmartUPS During a Power Failure - nixCraft

My Linux nas server connected to APC SmartUPS using usb cable and I would like to detect a power failure. If power is not restored my server must shutdown when the battery is exhausted. How do I configure and use my APC SmartUPS under Debina / Ubuntu...

It's rather complicated.

I don't have a usb cable going from computer to my UPS.
It does have network in and out connections on UPS.

Any front end for it?

Comment: If you don't have the USB cable connected, it's almost certainly not going to be able to shut down your computer.

Comment: Thanks. I found the cable and connected it. I now have a Power Manager applet.